# CSS3 animation doesn't work if div:before is floating (WebKit)

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations

I want my text to blink using CSS3 only. It works fine. However, if I add `float:left` to the div's `:before` selector, it stops the animation from working on WebKit (Safari/Chrome).

For demonstration, open [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/5299/) on WebKit, remove the `float:left` to see it working.

CSS:

```
.blink_me:before {
  content: "Blink";
}

.blink_me {
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite; 
}
@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="blink_me"> </span>
```

How can I make it work with the float on the selector?

BOUNTY info: just rewarding an existing answer which certainly deserves more upvotes.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on FF, but not on webkit. Interesting issue. +1

Comment: Add position:relative to the pseudo selector. Unfortunately I can't provide more information :D

Comment: @Tonsenson That doesn't answer the question respectfully. If you couldn't  provide *more information*, why bother commenting? :)

Comment: Just because I can't understand how this fixes it and maybe somebody who reads my comment can explain it and lighten us up :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Reason:

It definitely seems to be because of layer creation and accelerated rendering process in Webkit. Have a look at all the demos in this answer after enabling "Show Paint Rects"  and "Show Composited Layer Borders" option in Dev Tools.

When any one demo is run, you'd see some green and orange boxes. The green boxes are the paint rectangles whereas the orange boxes are the compositing layers that are created by rendering engine for accelerated rendering. During the rendering process, Webkit (and Blink) do not always repaint the entire page. Only affected areas (layers) of the page gets repainted (for performance).

**With Float:**

In this snippet, you'd see that the rendering engine creates one paint rectangle, a compositing layer for the page and one more paint rectangle, compositing layer for the `span` element (the "Some Content"). Since the `span`  is an `inline` element, it doesn't generate a [principal block-level box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) that contains its descendant's boxes and generated contents. This (per my understanding) makes the pseudo-element be floated with respect to the root element. It also means that the pseudo-element's position on-screen is not dependant on the parent `span` element (in fact, if you give a negative margin to the `span` you'd notice that the contents overlap whereas if `display: block` is set for `span` a negative margin moves the pseudo-element's content also to the left). Since the floated element's state doesn't affect the span and since it doesn't get its own compositing layer also, its opacity is not changed by the animation.

```css
.blink_me:before {
  content: "Blink";
  float: left;
}
.blink_me {
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me">Some content</span>
```

**Without Float:**

Here also the engine creates two layers + two paint rectangles but since there is no float, the pseudo-element is also `inline` and is a part of the parent `span` (you'd see one box covering the "Blink" and "Some content"). Now since the pseudo's content is also a part of the parent's layer, the animation on the parent affects the pseudo-element's content also.

```css
.blink_me:before {
  content: "Blink";
}
.blink_me {
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me">Some content</span>
```

---

#### Solutions:

Doing any one of the following things are resulting in the pseudo-element's content being treated as a part of the parent element's layer and hence the animation on parent is affecting the child also. When any one of these setting is applied, you'd again notice the orange border covering the span element's content and the pseudo-element's content.

- Setting any `position` on the pseudo-element (relative or absolute or even fixed).

  ```css
  .blink_me:before {
    content: "Blink";
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .blink_me {
    -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <span class="blink_me">Some content</span>
  ```
- Setting a `opacity` other than 1 on the pseudo-element (like 0.99 etc).

  ```css
  .blink_me:before {
    content: "Blink";
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.99;
  }
  .blink_me {
    -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <span class="blink_me">Some content</span>
  ```
- Setting `transform: translateZ(0px);` on the pseudo-element.

  ```css
  .blink_me:before {
    content: "Blink";
    float: left;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
  }
  .blink_me {
    -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <span class="blink_me">Some content</span>
  ```

Or, the other solution would be to set the animation directly on the pseudo-element because it then gets its own compositing layer and only that layer gets affected.

```css
.blink_me:before {
  content: "Blink";
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me"> </span>
```

Another option that is working is to set `display` as `inline-block` or `block` to parent `span`. This is also making the pseudo-element be a part of the parent element's compositing layer and hence it also is affected by the animation.

```css
.blink_me:before {
  content: "Blink";
  float: left;
}
.blink_me {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me"> </span>
```

---

#### Summary

In the second link that is provided under the References, you'd see how the rendering process works in WebKit (and Blink) right from Nodes to Render Objects to Render Layers to Compositing Layers.

The below is a summary of how those apply to all the demos in this answer and why it makes each of them work the way they are.

**When there is no float on the pseudo-element:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | No           | N/A
```

Here the `span` gets a render layer as soon as animation starts because it is semi-transparent (due to opacity) and it gets a compositing layer because it has opacity animation. The pseudo gets no render layer of its own because it doesn't satisfy any criteria required and so doesn't get a compositing layer either. It becomes a part of the first ancestor's render + compositing layer. During the compositing, the pseudo's content is also affected because it is also a part of the layer.

**When there is float on the pseudo-element:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | No           | N/A
```

Same as previous but since there is a float and it is not part of the `span`, the pseudo is not part of its compositing layer and hence not modified during the compositing operation.

**When the pseudo-element is positioned:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | No
```

When the psuedo is positioned, it gets a render layer of its own (as it matches the criteria) but doesn't get a compositing layer because it doesn't match the criteria required for that. Also, the positioning on it means that its position on-screen is affected by any transforms on the span. It looks as though this makes the pseudo-element also become a part the span's compositing layer and hence gets modified as part of the compositing operation.

**When the pseudo-element has opacity less than 1:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | No
```

Similar case to the previous one. Here the pseudo having an opacity less than 1 means that it needs to change when a layer below it changes (otherwise, transparency will be spoiled).  Because of that, this seems to get moved to the compositing layer and so is modified during compositing.

**When the pseudo-element has a transform:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
```

Here, the pseudo also get its own compositing layer because it has a 3D transform on it and since it is the child of the `span`, its layer is above the span's layer. This means that during compositing, both the span and the pseudo-element's layers are modified and thus  animation affects the pseudo here also.

**When pseudo-element is directly animated:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | No           | N/A
:before | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
```

Here, the `span` gets no render or compositing layer because the opacity animation is on the pseudo element. Since  pseudo gets its own compositing layer, here also it is affected during compositing.

**When span has display as block or inline-block:**

```
Element | Node  | Render Object | Render Layer | Compositing Layer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes (Descendant is a compositing layer)
span    | Yes   | Yes           | Yes          | Yes
:before | Yes   | Yes           | No           | N/A
```

This is very similar to the case where the pseudo element is floated but since here the span is a block level element, it generates the principal block level box for its descendants and generated content. So, the pseudo gets to be part of the span's compositing layer and thus is affected during compositing.

> **Note:** The whole rendering process is very complex as you could see from the reference links and I've tried my best to explain the process. There are chances that I could have some of the intricate details wrong but on the overall you'd find that the explanation tallies with the Dev tools output.

---

#### References:

You can find more information about how to enable the "Show Paint Rects", "Show Composited Layer Borders" options and also on how the accelerated rendering process works by referring to the below links:

- [HTML5 Rocks - Accelerated Rendering in Chrome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/)
- [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome).

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Although it doesn't answer the question directly, it does offer a genuine solution to it. Will accept in a moment.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: Yes, I would love to give you a direct answer (and I am trying). Don't accept the answer, not atleast for a few hours because questions with accepted answers get less views and could put off potential answerers.

Comment: Yea, it could be relevant @HenrikPetterson but what I found is that this issue not just happens for pseudo-elements. It happens even if we float a child element inside a parent element whose display is inline. Even more interesting is the fact that `position: relative` on the child/pseudo-element solves it too (as pointed out in comments to question).

Comment: The floated `:before` is a own box. If you inspect the elements with float the `:before` is a box and the `span` is a own box! The animation could not affect the floated `:before`, but other properties like `color` are working. That's strange. Little Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/5304/

Comment: No, I was just waiting for this question to be eligible for a bounty so that I can reward you for the outstanding answer. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much mate. @HenrikPetterson There are still a few minor loose ends in my answer. Hopefully the bounty could attract more people and maybe you get an even more complete answer too :)